# PushNotification Staus Code 200 but not Receiving Message

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

After successfully sent the URI to the web service from the push client, I send a toast notification from web service by using the URI, in web service I get the response as :

Push status 200,
NotificationStatus : Received,
DeviceConnectionStatus : Connected,
NotificationChannelStatus : Active.

But no message is received in the push client. The same scenario used to work fine earlier today. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web service, if a wrong setRequestProperty is set for example, setting wrong X-WindowsPhone-Target and wrong X-NotificationClass, then web service will receive notification received status, but the push client will not receive any message.

In my case I was sending a toast message with X-WindowsPhone-Target as token and X-NotificationClass as 1. After giving correct value it has started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the message you are sending the same (ie. identical)?  I seem to remember that some instances of a malformed message would get through the service OK, but then be suppressed on the device.

Do you have code to handle toast messages that arrive while your app is running?  If you do, put a breakpoint in there and send a toast to the app while you're debugging and see what comes out.  In this way you can make sure that the toast is making it to the device, and also see what the content is or what the problem might be.

```
channel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += channel_ShellToastNotificationReceived;
```

where `channel` is your channel object, and then

```
void channel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Collection["wp:Text1"] + Environment.NewLine + e.Collection["wp:Text2"]));
}
```

or something similar to pop the message out to the display.

Comment: I was sending the same message repeatedly. But now I changed the message and tested. still getting the same issue. Also I already have added code for handling toast messages when the app is running. I added break point and checked already, but break point is not even hit. But all used to work fine earlier.